# Ruby on Rails: undefined method 'new_token' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and i've come into an error I can't figure out.

I keep getting the following error, NoMethodError: undefined method 'new_token' for User. This happens when im simply just trying to create an instance of User or if I just call User from the console

The code below is dumbed down as I tried to isolate the issue by commenting out some of the other methods

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token

      validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
      validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
      validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil: true
      has_secure_password

      def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
       end
      def User.new_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end
   end
```

When I try to something simply in the console like returning the first user, I get this error:

```
2.2.0 :019 > User.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `new_token' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Jshyu/Desktop/Jitter/app/models/user.rb:15:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/Desktop/Jitter/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):19
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/Desktop/Jitter/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.0 :020 >
```

EDIT:

Whats even more weird is when I comment out the class method self.new_token I get a different error, NameError: undefined local variable or method ' ' for User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil: true
  has_secure_password
  #Returns the hash digest of the given string
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
#   def self.new_token
#     SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
#   end
end

2.2.0 :026 > User
NameError: undefined local variable or method `  ' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Jshyu/Desktop/Jitter/app/models/user.rb:22:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/Desktop/Jitter/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):26
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/Desktop/Jitter/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Jshyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.0 :027 >
```

I recently installed sublimelinter and rubocop, but since removed them...

Comment: What's your code when you try to create User instance in the console?

Comment: From your error log, it seems that you tried to call `new_token` as a class method, which it is not.

Comment: try to change `def User.new_token` to `def new_token`

Comment: @TheF I tried changing it to self.new_token to see if that would help but it didn't either

Comment: @Jshoe523 I've tried the model code you have above (both with and without `User.new_token` and I don't get any errors, so there must be something else causing the error. Is that all of your model code? What exactly is `User.new_token` for? Is there a gem or something else that calls this value? (Also FWIW class methods are usually defined with `self.method_name` not `ClassName.method_name`, since the former makes the code more portable and less verbose.)

Comment: look at https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition for more help

Comment: @eirikir this is code I got from a tutorial i'm following. I commented out the other methods for now since I'm just trying to focus on this one error. I think this started ever since I installed sublime linter and rubocop

Comment: The linter may be causing an issue. Have you tried other IDEs? Maybe vim as a text editor? Rubocop would not cause the error. I killing the rails server and trying again, without the linter.

Answer (score -1):

Quit rails console and restart the server.  Try again!